# TOP vs df -h command memory shows different

Tags: memory, solaris, disk-usage, top

I am using solaris 10.

Can someone please help me why both command shows different total memory?

df -h command shows memory total memory SIZE is 900G

```
~=>df -h /test
Filesystem          Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
/test               900G   745G       146G    84%    /test
```

TOP command shows 255G real memory

```
Memory: 255G real, 126G free, 103G swap in use, 167G swap free
```

---

Also please explain what is SIZE and RES memory in below top command?
I am aware RES is RAM(Physical memory) then what is SIZE

```
 PID USERNAME THR PRI NICE  SIZE  RES  STATE   TIME   CPU COMMAND
18256 test    55  59    0  667M  476M  sleep   0:45  0.12% java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
```

tells you the size of the disk but not the memory
where the `top` command tells you the amount of memory on the system.

```
free -h
```

Provides memory information.

Comment: Except `free` is not a *Solaris* command (try the vmstat and/or swap commands).